# How to get the link of the app in appstore before submission

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm developing an application on IOS devices, however i want to know how to get the link of the application before publishing it, so i can integrate an Action Sheet to let the user choose weather he wants to leave a review on the app-store.

I connected to iTunes Connect, and when i clicked on view the app in the app store, however I'm getting error that says that the app is in the US store, and I'm developing on the Oman store !.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, i hope someone can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need your applicationBundleID to navigate user to appstore. You can refer link  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate In this you just need to write following code in AppDelegate

```
#import "iRate.h"
+ (void)initialize
{
    [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"com.xxxx.projectName";//Your application bundle identifire
    [iRate sharedInstance].usesUntilPrompt=3;
    [iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt=0;
}
```

You did not need to add alert. This framework will display the popup. I think this is what you want. Hope it is useful to you...

Answer (score 3):

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id{ADD YOUR REGISTERD APP ID}

You can get your app id from iTunes connect. Its unique for each application.

> Note : In development phase you will get error but once application
>   become live that error will not appear.
>
> If you wanna try then get app id of any existing live app & add it in
>   above URL.
>
> You can get app id of any application by just googling the name of
>   that application